# OOP PHP Errors while querying mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm just starting with OOP, and while using a tutorial I encountered the following errors:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for MySQLDatabase::query(), called in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/object-oriented/public/index.php on line 7 and defined in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/object-oriented/includes/database.php on line 28

Notice: Undefined variable: sql in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/object-oriented/includes/database.php on line 29

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/object-oriented/includes/database.php on line 29
```

Here is my database.php

```
<?php

require('config.php');

class MySQLDatabase {

    public $connection;

    public function open_connection() {
        $this->$connection = mysqli_connect('DB_SERVER', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS');
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed");
        } else {
            $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);
            if (!$select_db) {
                die("Database selection failed");
            }
        }
    }

    public function close_connection() {
        if (isset($this->connection)) {
            mysqli_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($connection, $sql) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

and my index.php in which I'm trying to test the query() method.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, first_name, last_name) ";
$sql .= "VALUES (1, 'andrei', 'password', 'Andrei', 'Popa')";
$result = $database->query($sql);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
$found_user = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
echo "Found user!" . $found_user['username'];
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your query function expects two parameters. You're passing it one - though you don't need to pass it `$connection`, as it's never used (you're using the object's $connection property instead)

Comment: read the error messages, they seem rather clear

Answer (score 1):

```
public function query($connection, $sql) {
```

You don't need the first parameter, as the the connection is property of your class. So only pass `$sql` into the query method as you already did when using the method:

```
public function query($sql) {
```

Comment: Fixed that. Now I get  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/object-oriented/includes/database.php on line 29

Answer (score 1):

This is your definition:

```
public function query($connection, $sql) {
```

and this is your call:

```
$result = $database->query($sql);
```

You need to add a connection :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of errors:

**First**

```
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);
if (!$select_db) {
```

check varibables `db_select` and `select_db`

**Second**:

```
public function query($connection, $sql) {

$result = $database->query($sql);
```

you need to check your arguments. I think, you need to remove $connection from declaration

```
public function query($sql) {
```

because next you are using class variable:

```
$this->connection;
```

**Third**:

```
public function open_connection()
```

there is no counstructor in your class and you don't call method `open_connection`, as a result: you active connection is `NULL`

You need to add this method to your class:

```
function __construct() {
    open_connection();
}
```

Comment: Fixed the problems, sorry about $select_db, typo. After using the construct method i end up with: 

` Fatal error: Call to undefined function open_connection() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/object-oriented/includes/database.php on line 59`

Comment: Sorry, `$this->open_connection();` of cause.